# Symfony2 Generating Forms | Call to undefined method Entity::GetName() in FormFactory.php on line 192

Tags: forms, doctrine, symfony

I created a form in symfony2, the form has a one to Many relationship.

when I try to print the form in the template, it says:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method X\XBundle\Entity\RepresentanteLegal::getName() in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\X\vendor\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory.php on line 192
```

I don't have a getName() function on RepresentanteLegal because I don't have a Name attribute.

So, I need some help.

I have generated a form in the project and I didn't have any trouble.

This is RepresentanteLegalType:

```
namespace Sofla\SoflaBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class RepresentanteLegalType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('nombre')
        ->add('apellido')
        ->add('telefonoCelular')
        ->add('telefonoLocal')
    ;
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'sofla_soflabundle_representantelegaltype';
    }
}
```

and this is the construct of RepresentanteLegal.php

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->empresa = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

Also, in RepresentanteLegal.php there are attributes,  getters and setters but I won't post them here because I believe that is not relevant.

EDIT: I found the solution, it was because I was calling:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new RepresentanteLegal(), $hojadevida);
```

and not

```
$form = $this->createForm(new RepresentanteLegalType(), $hojadevida);
```

I'm so sorry. My mistake...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should supply your form with default form name. Create function in your form class

```
public function getName()
    {
        return 'empressa_form';
    }
```

Comment: It does exist. But it doesn't work. Symfony2 is telling me that it needs the getName function in Empresa.php class, in the Form Class it already exists. But why?

Comment: can you please post your forms constructor code? And try adding {{ form_rest(form) }} to the end of your template

Comment: I edited the question, there are the codes. I'll try form_rest(form) but I believe the problem is not in the template, it's before it gets there.